# Store data from text to mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql-python

'NBN3W27800D1.NS'
3326.5
3515.6
3326.5
'2021-04-13'
3515.6

3904.0
3970.3
27800
'2021-04-15'
'NBN3W27800P1.NS'
6.55
13.0
4.1
'2021-04-13'
9.25

5.6
6.55
27800
'2021-04-15'

my text file contains these data. i want to store as 2 rows into mysql - db

Comment: You have to provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a.k.a. Your efforts on solving this issue

Comment: I can tell You already that You want to first open the file, then `.readlines()` it and for that list do a for loop and add each item in that list to Your database

Comment: As others have said, open() and readlines() with use of split() will parse your data.
Go look at pyodbc for interfacing python with a database. Have a go at it and come back if you have problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I assume You want (get each line of text and store them in separate rows):

```
with open('your_file.txt') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

for line in data:
    print(line)
```

Except replace the `print` with whatever function You use to add to the database and just use a counter or `enumerate()` to set the row like so:

```
for row, line in enumerate(data):
    print(row, line)
```

except again replace that print with insertion to database.

You may also want to add `.strip()` to remove the newlines:

```
for lines in data:
    lines = lines.strip()
    print(lines)
```

and again add the rest of the database code (which I don't know so I am giving You print fucntions)